# PyTorch CUDA: Error when trying to move Tensor to the GPU

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

The following snippet is a simple example of moving a Torch Tensor to the GPU.

```
import torch

device = torch.device('cuda:0' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

psum = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).to(device)
psum_sq = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).to(device)

total_mean = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).to(device)
total_std = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).to(device)
```

Ran the code and got the following error.

```
File "F:\Sliding_Windows\classifier\dataloader.py", line 118, in calculate_image_stats
    psum = torch.tensor([0.0, 0.0, 0.0]).to(device)
RuntimeError: CUDA error: invalid argument
```

Reinstalled PyTorch but that did not change a thing (Torch 1.10.2, CUDA10.2).
Changed the device from `cuda:0` to `cpu` and the operation worked.

The error message is not very intuitive. What could possibly be the reason that the CPU version works while the GPU version fails?

Comment: did you install pytorch using the following command?
pip install torch
if yes, please uninstall it and install using the following link
pip install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu100/torch-1.1.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
This is the correct way to install given on pytorch platform.

Comment: I installed PyTorch with the command from the official website: pip3 install torch==1.10.2+cu102 torchvision==0.11.3+cu102 torchaudio===0.10.2+cu102 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu102/torch_stable.html.